# Verificar contraseña con PHP y DB?

Tags: php, contraseña

mi objetivo es crear un sistema de registros y logueos básico. De momento tengo el registro que funciona correctamente y manda la información a la BD.

Del login me lee hasta el verificar la contraseña, que parece que no lo hace correctamente porque salta como si la escribiera mal (obviamente no es así).+

$uname es el nombre de usuario que escribe el usuario en el login
$pass es la contraseña que escriben en el loguin

PHP

```
    include 'conn.php';

      echo "<script>
      console.log('Comienza el login');
      </script>";

      //Meto los valores que nos ha dado en el campo de iniciar sesión.
      $uname = $_POST['uname'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      echo $uname;
      echo $pass;
      //Verificamos si existe un usuario con ese nombre

      $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uname = '$uname'");

      if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "existe ese nombre de usuario";

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      }
        //Cogemos la contraseña de la BD

        if (password_verify($pass, $row['user_pass'])) {
          $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
          $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
          $_SESSION['start'] = time();

          echo "Sesión iniciada" . $_SESSION['username'];
        }
        else {
           echo "Username o password incorrectos";

        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
```

el HTML

```
      <form action="includes/login.php" method="POST" id="login">
        <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control navbarlogin" name="uname">
        <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control navbarlogin" name="pass">
        <span class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_submit">Iniciar sesión</span>
  </form>
```

el JS

```
 var login = document.getElementById('login');

document.getElementById('btn_submit').onclick = function() {

  login.submit();
  console.log('Se ha enviado el login');
}
```

Comment: Por alguna razón se me ha puesto el codigo dividido, va todo junto

Comment: Necesitamos saber la función "password_verify" qué código tiene.
Si dices que el problema es que no te funciona bien la parte de la verificación de la contraseña... necesitamos tener ese código también.

Cuando haces echo $uname y $pass..los imprime en pantalla bien?

En la base de datos, el campo de "uname" me imagino que es único verdad? No puede haber dos nombres de usuario iguales, a ver si resulta que hay 2 idénticos y tú intentas darle el pass del segundo... fallaría siempre

Comment: Si, los imprime correctamente, y el password verify lo he sacado de internet, creia que era una funcion de php o algo que directamente comprobaba la contraseña que ponia el usuario ($pass)  con la de la BD ($row ['user_pass']

Comment: Añade a tu publicación el código de esa función para que podamos ver qué hace.
Aunque de todos modos, lo que podrías hacer para ahorrar pasos, es que en tu consulta, ya le pases el usuario y contraseña y busques si existe algún registro que cumpla ambas condiciones. En vez de consultar por un lado el usuario y por otro la contraseña.

Comment: Disculpa que sea tan bobo, estoy aprendiendo aún haha, pero a que función te refieres?

Comment: Necesitamos la definición de la función password_verify.

Comment: Ah, no lo se, creía que se ponía y ya, la saque de internet haha. Entonces seguro que no hace nada si hay que definirlo, me podría ayudar?

Comment: No veo en que consulta te estas trayendo el password. Normalmente como yo lo hago me traigo el password en un select y en el campo password coloco el dato que el usuario colocó en el input si la query se cumple es porque el usuario colocò bien sus datos.

Comment: Después de leer todos estos comentarios y la respuesta dada al op, me pregunto ¿Nadie encripta las contraseñas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como alternativa, lo que te decía por los comentarios de antes.
Vamos a ver si el proceso de logueo es válido o no lo es con sólo una consulta a la base de datos y así, de paso, te ahorras la función password_verify

```
include 'conn.php';

echo "<script>
console.log('Comienza el login');
</script>";

//Meto los valores que nos ha dado en el campo de iniciar sesión.
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
echo $uname;
echo $pass;
//Verificamos si existe un usuario con ese nombre

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uname = '$uname' and [CAMPO_PASSWORD] = '$pass'");

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo "existe ese nombre de usuario";

  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
  $_SESSION['start'] = time();

  echo "Sesión iniciada" . $_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
   echo "Username o password incorrectos";

}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Sólo cambia el [CAMPO_PASSWORD] por el nombre del campo de tu base de datos donde almacenes la contraseña.

Comment: Conexion a la base de datos exitosaPipoguauexiste ese nombre de usuarioSesión iniciadaPipo

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, parece que ya inicia

Comment: Si la contraseña esta encriptada como es lo recomendable eso no funcionara, para eso se utiliza la funcion `password_verify` vease la documentacion: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

Comment: +50 puntos paa @Xerif, no conocía esa función nativa de php. Siempre lo hice con clases propias. =)

Answer (score 2):

En cualquier sistema con un mínimo de seguridad deberian almacenarse las contraseñas en la base de datos cifradas, para ayudarnos en esta tarea PHP provee las siguientes funciones:

**password_verify()**

> La función `password_verify()` sirve para comparar un string (contraseña) contra un hash. Podemos ver la documentación en el siguiente enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php

**password_hash()**

> Para que tu codigo funcione las contraseñas deben estar cifradas en la base de datos, por ejemplo con la función `password_hash()`, documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Un ejemplo para encriptar y posteriormente verificar la contradeña:

```
// Generar el hash cuando creamos la contraseña
// este hash sera el que se guarde en la base de datos 
// en lugar de la contraseña en texto plano
$hash = password_hash('unacontraseña', CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

// ejemplo de resulrado de password_hash
// $2y$10$MUhTQ7wl9/J0w7soKfRdL.Hg2PKvwOA0oInnmBZbXPdOukf6Wc8xC

// Verificar la contraseña:
if (password_verify('unacontraseña', $hash)) {
    echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
} else {
    echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
}
// Resultado:
// ¡La contraseña es válida!
```

Verificar la contraseña desde una base de datos Mysql utilizando sentencias preparadas:

```
// se asume conexion en $conn
// se asume contraseña guardada en un campo llamado: pass

/* preparamos la consulta */
// añadimos un LIMIT 1 ya que solo esperamos un resultado
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT user_uname, pass FROM users WHERE user_uname = ? LIMIT 1")) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    // en este caso el nombre de usuario
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['uname']);
    /* ejecutamos la query */
    $stmt->execute();
    /* recuperamos los resultados */
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    /* recuperamos la fila como un array asociativo */
    $fila = $result->fetch_assoc()


    // Verificar si la contraseña coincide
    if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $fila['pass'])) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
        // hacer lo que corresponda
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
        // hacer lo que corresponda
    }



} else {
    echo 'Error al preparar la consulta SQL'
}
```

> A parte de lo indicado anteriormente el código de tu pregunta es vulnerave a [inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Si, lo se, pero es para un trabajo de clase, asi que no pasa nada haha