# Problema al comparar contraseñas con password verify

Tags: php, mysql, hash

saque el hash de la contraseña usando la funcion password_hash y almacene el hash en una base de datos mysql

en solucioncontroller.php intento verificar el hash contraseña pero no funciona

```
class solucionController {
include_once 'model/solucion.php';

public function Login()
{
    $solucion = new solucion();
    if (isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
    {
        $login = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["login"]));
        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
        $solucion = $this->model->Logeo($login, $password);
        $pass= $this->model->getpass();
        if (password_verify($password, $pass)&&$solucion == 1)
        {
            setcookie('usuario', $login, time() + 3600);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["Usuario"] = $login;
            header("Location: view/header.php");
            header("Location: view/solucion/solucion.php");
            header("Location: view/Footer.php");
        }
    }
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}
}
```

en el modelo solucion.php busco el hash almacenado en pass por el usuario ingresado en la vista de inicio de sesión

```
class solucion {
public $res;


 public function Logeo($login) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT pass FROM logeo WHERE usuario = :login";
        $resultado = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
        $resultado->execute();
        $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount();
        if ($numero_registro != 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        $this->res = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function getpass(){
return $this->res['pass'];
}

}

public function getpass(){
    return $this->res['pass'];
}
```

en la vista login está el formulario donde ingreso el nombre de usuario y la contraseña

```
<?php 
if(isset($_COOKIE['usuario'])){
require 'view/solucion/solucion.php';
}
else{


?>
<a class="btn btn-success pull-right" href="?c=solucion&a=Invitado">Invitado</a>
<h1>Introduce tus datos</h1>
    <form action="?c=solucion&a=Login" method="post">
        <div class="container">
        <label for="login"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese usuario" name="login" required>
<label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese Contraseña" name="password" required>
<button type="submit">Login</button>             
            </div>
        </form>
<?php }?>
```

Al ingresar el nombre de usuario y la contraseña, los datos se eliminan y permanezco en la vista de inicio de sesión

Comment: Por qué usas htmlentities y addslashes sobre el valor de la contraseña? No es un valor que vayas a mostrar en pantalla y sí vas a deformarlo, por lo que la comparación puede fallar dependiendo de lo que el usuario elija como contraseña. Aparte de eso, session_start() no se usa así; en la documentación indica que se ejecuta antes de mostrar cualquier cosa en pantalla. Por último, yo no guardaría contraseñas en texto en claro, así que yo no compararía el texto de la contraseña sino que usaría bcrypt y compararía el hash generado con el almacenado

Comment: Estas comparando una contraseña en claro con una contraseña en hash

Comment: ¿Por qué a `Logeo()` le pasas 2 parámetros si solo admite uno? ¿Por qué tienes 2 veces declarado el mismo método `getpass()` en la misma clase? Aquí puedes encontrar un ejemplo de `password_verify`  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%c3%b1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704