# Error en cambiar contraseña usando Ajax/MySQLi sentencias preparadas(orientado a objetos)?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

No estoy seguro si el procedimiento, de permitir al usuario cambiar su contraseña es el correcto.

El `Ajax` funciona bien, porque me muestra errores, como lo siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\changepass.php on line 48
>   Warning: password_hash() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\changepass.php on line 48
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\changepass.php on line 65

Me pueden explicar como permitir al usuario cambiar su contraseña correctamente.
Es necesario que el formulario se oculte, y muestre el mensaje de ***¡Contraseña cambiada con éxito!***

**changepass.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['password_change'])) {
    $hash = password_hash($password);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['old_password']);
    $old_password = $hash;
    $newpassword = strip_tags($_POST['new_password']);
    $new_password = $hash;
    $confirmnewpassword = strip_tags($_POST['con_newpassword']);
    $con_newpassword = $hash;

    $stmtUsers=$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where username=? limit 1");
    $stmtUsers->bind_param("s",$username);

    if($stmtUsers->execute()) {
        $hash = $stmtUsers->fetch();
        if ($password == $hash['password']){
            if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword) {
                $stmtUpdate=$con->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
                $stmtUpdate->bind_param("ss",$newpassword,$username);
                if($stmtUpdate->execute()){
                    echo "¡Contraseña cambiada con éxito!";
                } else{
                    echo "La contraseña no se pudo actualizar";
                }
            } else {
                echo "¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Por favor, escriba su contraseña actual con precisión!";

        }
    } else {
        echo "Nombre de usuario incorrecto";
    }
}
```

**Formulario**

```
<form name="resetform" action="changepass.php" id="resetform" class="passform" method="post" role="form">
    <h3>Change Your Password</h3>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" ></input>
    <label>Enter Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="old_password" id="old_password">
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" id="new_password">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="con_newpassword"  id="con_newpassword" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="password_change" id="submit_btn" value="Change Password" />
</form>

<!--display success/error message-->
<div id="message"></div>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var frm = $('#resetform');
    frm.submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = frm.serialize();
        formData += '&' + $('#submit_btn').attr('name') + '=' + $('#submit_btn').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            success: function(data){
                $('#message').html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(3000);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#message').html(textStatus).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            }

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Estructura de la tabla de usuarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, el error esta porque la función password_hash, toma dos parámetros y solo le pasas uno, el $password. Te adjunto el link de la documentación. http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta respuesta que di hace algún tiempo puedes ver el uso de `password_verify` y `password_hash` https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166704/38103

En base a eso revisemos tu código:

```
if (isset($_POST['password_change'])) {
    // Asignamos variables
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $old_password = $_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password = $_POST['new_password'];
    $con_password = $_POST['con_newpassword'];

    // comprobamos que las password coinciden
    if($con_password !== $new_password){
        echo "¡Las contraseñas no coinciden!";
        exit;
    }

    // Buscamos el usuario 
    $stmtUsers = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username=? limit 1");
    $stmtUsers->bind_param("s", $username);
    // validamos consulta
    if(!$stmtUsers->execute()) {
        echo 'Error nose pudo ejecutar la consulta';
        exit;
    }
    //obtenemos el resultado
    if(!$result = $stmtUsers->fetch()){
        echo "Nombre de usuario incorrecto";
        exit;
    }

    // validamos password bd con la introducida
    if (!password_verify($old_password, $result['password'])) {
        echo '¡La contraseña no es válida!';
        exit;
    }

    // si llegamos hasta aquí todo esta en orden y actualizamos


    // cifrados la password antes de guardarla recuerda
    $hash = password_hash($new_password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);

    $stmtUpdate = $con->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmtUpdate->bind_param("ss", $hash, $username);
    if($stmtUpdate->execute()){
        echo "¡Contraseña cambiada con éxito!";
    } else{
         echo "La contraseña no se pudo actualizar";
    }
}
```

Comment: Haz un `print_r($result['password']);` y revisa que te esta retornando la base de datos, fijate que a la consulta le quite el `count(*)` y lo deje como `*` para poder obtener la password y resto de datos de la base de datos.

Comment: Despues del `if` de obtener resultados y antes del `if` del `password_verify`, si no te muestra nada es por que no te esta trayendo esa columna de la base de datos(puede que tenga otro nombre) o la contraseña esta vacia. ¿Puedes poner un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla`?

Comment: Y sí le agrego esto `!` a: `if (!password_verify('123', $password))` me dice que la contraseña no es valida.

Comment: Ya lo solucione tuve que realizar una consulta normal, porque el procedimiento `$stmtUsers = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where username=? limit 1");` que estabas realizando no trae datos, puedes explicarme un poco sobre esto `$hash = password_hash($new_password, CRYPT_BLOWFISH);`

Comment: @Fernando me alegra que lo solucionaras. En cuanto a `password_hash()` y `password_verify()` no tienen mucho mas que explicar, en el enlace de la respuesta tienes un ejemplo. Se recomienda usar la constante `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` y tambien puedes pasar un tercer parametro indicando el coste, por defecto es 10, Ejemplo: `password_hash($Pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 20])`. Existe una tercera funcion `password_needs_rehash()` para determinar si el hash se ha quedado desfasado respecto a las opciones de encriptado actuales, por ejemplo si se incrementa el coste.