# ¿Cómo agregar más comprobaciones de validación en archivo PHP json_encode?

Tags: php, json

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de registro usando `ajax` esta vez de una manera muy distinta a una de mis pregunta [anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/188295/error-en-cambiar-contrase%C3%B1a-usando-ajax-mysqli-sentencias-preparadasorientado-a) realizando algunos cambios.

Esta vez usando `json_encode` para recibir personalizad-amente los mensajes de error en mi archivo `ajax` al recibir 
una respuesta correcta mediante unn `status` `true` realizo una acción muy diferente a las respuestas erróneas mediante el `status` `false`.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo agregar más comprobaciones de la misma acción o el mismo dato usando la misma tecnología empleada, si bien cierto que al enviar los campos `input` vacíos, el Ajax me trae la respuesta, pero no existe una validación del `emeil` cualquier dato erróneo puede ser recibido en el registro de la tabla de datos.

¿Cómo válido el email, mediante un `status=>false` mencionado qué el email ingresado no es válido, es caso de así serlo.

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])){
     echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"Por favor ingresé su email."]]);
     exit;
}
```

De la misma forma es necesario agregar otras validaciones al campo `password`, al momento se válida que ambas contraseñas deben ser iguales, pero me faltaría agregar un mínimo de carácteres de longitud del `password` de 6 y un máximo de 20 carácteres, entre ella debe tener un carácter especial, un dígito o número, una letra mayúscula y una letra minúscula.

```
if($password_again !== $password){
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["password" =>"Las contraseñas no coinciden"]]);
    exit;
}
```

Me pueden explicar cómo puedo realizar este procedimiento, yo puedo realizarlo de una manera distinta, pero al usar esté mismo procedimiento de `status false` deben existir otro procedimiento y a lo mejor hasta algunas recomendaciones.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien qué problema tienes. ¿Es por qué no sabes poner los dos mensajes de error (el de falta correo y el de la clave) juntos en lugar de devolverlos por separado?

Comment: Hola @JavierMollá sí exactamente lo que usted dice, he actualizado me pregunta para que esté más claro :)

Comment: el email lo podes comprobar con `if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { `

Comment: ¿Alguna novedad? ¿Conseguiste solucionar tu duda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías replantearte la forma en la que devuelves los mensajes de error.

No pasa nada si tienes un único campo de `status`, pero si sólo tienes uno de `messages` entonces deberías usarlo como matriz para poder introducir varios mensajes en vez de únicamente uno.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$resultado = [
  'status' => true,
  'messages' => [],
];
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
  /* Marcamos como error la petición */
  $resultado['status'] = false;
  /* Agregamos un nuevo mensaje a la matriz de mensajes */
  $resultado['messages'][] = [
    'email' => 'Por favor, introduzca su correo.'
  ];
}
if($_POST['password_again'] !== $_POST['password']) {
  /* No importa si asignamos por segunda vez un valor "false" */
  $resultado['status'] = false;
  /* Agregamos un nuevo mensaje a la matriz de mensajes */
  $resultado['messages'][] = [
    'password' => 'Las contraseñas no coinciden.'
  ];
}
/* Si se permiten caracteres utf-8 hay que usar funciones mb_* */
if(
  mb_strlen($_POST['password']) < 6
  || mb_strlen($_POST['password']) > 20
  || mb_ereg_match('[a-z]', $_POST['password']) === false
  || mb_ereg_match('[A-Z]', $_POST['password']) === false
  || mb_ereg_match('[0-9]', $_POST['password']) === false
  || mb_ereg_match('[._\\\[\]\-=+:]', $_POST['password']) === false
) {
  $resultado['status'] = false;
  /* Nuevo mensaje descriptivo */
  $resultado['messages'][] = [
    'password' => 'Las contraseñas deben cumplir:
- Tener entre 6 y 20 caracteres.
- Tener al menos una letra minúscula.
- Tener al menos una letra mayúscula.
- Tener al menos un número.
- Tener al menos uno de los siguientes caracteres: ._\\[]-=+:'
  ];
}
/* En caso de haberse producido un error enviamos inmediatamente el resultado */
if ($resultado['status'] === false) {
  die(json_encode($resultado));
}
/* En caso contrario borramos messages (matriz vacía) si es necesario */
unset($resultado['messages']);
/* Hacemos el trabajo (dar de alta o lo que sea) */
/* ... */
/* Y finalmente enviamos el resultado */
die(json_encode($resultado));
```

Comment: @OscatGarcia gracias, es buena vista, pero el código ésta adaptado correctamente, los mensajes de error se introduce en cada campo donde es el error, pero más allá de eso tenía otra visión de respuesta sobre dar validaciones de email y password.

Comment: Tu pregunta es **¿cómo puedo agregar más comprobaciones de la misma acción o el mismo dato usando la misma tecnología empleada?**. Espero haber respondido a tu pregunta. Si no era eso lo que preguntabas agradecería que me lo explicaras un poco más por si puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Ya he visto una segunda pregunta (no deberías preguntar más de una cosa en la misma pregunta) acerca de cómo implementar la comprobación de longitud de clave, una minúscula, mayúscula, dígito y carácter especial. Voy a editar mi respuesta para agregar eso.

Comment: Ya está. He editado mi respuesta agregando la comprobación de longitud y requisitos mínimos de la contraseña. Si no permites caracteres utf-8 (ñ, á, é, í.. ü, ¡, ¿, etc) entonces deberías filtrar o comprobar el contenido antes.

Comment: Podrías hacer la comprobación de longitud y contenido en una única línea con [`^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[._\\\[\]\-=+:]).{6,20}$` (ver online)](https://regex101.com/r/fhIbtL/1/tests).

Comment: Me he guiado con el ejemplo planteado, quería aclarar que solo el `messages` es para el estado `status true` es decir que al momento que todo esté bien los datos enviando se oculta el formulario y me muestra un mensaje en aquella condición, en un lugar determinado. En cambio los otros mensajes de error se inserta automáticamente en el campo que está el error por eso no lo hago a que sea de una manera matriz globalizada :) saludos! Gracias por responder.

Answer (score 1):

Realizar validaciones de email, entre ellas, dirección de email no validas: `algo@algo`, para ello, vamos a utilizar las expresiones [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php), sin cambiar la temática de la pregunta.

La expresión la puedes agregar desde la misma dependencia, entre un `else`

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])){
     echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"Por favor ingresé su email."]]);
     exit;
} else {
    if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"u dirección de correo electrónico no es válida"]]);
        exit;
    } 
}
```

O ala vez, de la siguiente manera, ya que la base de las validaciones es mostrar solo los mensajes de errores de la misma.

```
if (empty($_POST['email'])){
     echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"Por favor ingresé su email."]]);
     exit;
}

    if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
        echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["email" =>"u dirección de correo electrónico no es válida"]]);
        exit;
    }
```

Requerimientos de `Password`, mediante una misma expresión regular:

- Puede contener letras y números
- Debe contener al menos 1 número y 1 letra
- Puede contener cualquiera de estos caracteres: !@#$%
- Debe tener 8-20 caracteres

  ```
  if(!preg_match('/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9A-Za-z@#\-_$%^&+=§!\?]{8,20}$/',$password)){
  echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["password" =>"su mensaje personalizado"]]);
  exit;}
  ```

Otras alternantes de distintas formas de emplearlo.

- [Mediante uso de strlen( $password) < 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721811/regular-expression-for-a-password-with-at-least-8-characters-and-at-least-1-non)
- [Funciones de cadenas PHP de múltiples bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661832/php-multibyte-string-functions/661872#661872)
- [Regex para contraseña PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141125/regex-for-password-php)

> [Referencia - Validación de contraseña](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar esta función de PHP como para validar caracteres y estructura:

```
<?php

$sanitized_email= filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["password" =>"Las contraseñas no coinciden"]]);
    exit;
}
```