# password_hash y password_verify como usarlos - problema en php

Tags: php

hola buenas tardes la cosa es que ya logre encriptar la contrasena con el password_hash, en la bd sale encriptada... pero no logro  iniciar sesion porq no se si use bien o no el password _verify  lo q hice fue lo siguiente :

```html
session_cache_expire(1);
session_start();


$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];

$validacion = $bd->query("SELECT * from usuario where correo = '$correo' and  contrasena = '$contrasena'" );



$desencriptar_contrasena = password_verify($contrasena, $contrasena);

if ( mysqli_num_rows($validacion)){

  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($validacion);
  $_SESSION['usuario_id'] = $row['usuario_id'];
  $_SESSION['correo'] = $row['correo'];
  $_SESSION['contrasena'] = $row['contrasena'];
  $_SESSION['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
  $_SESSION['rol'] = $row['rol_id_rol'];
```

claro esta como dije no se como usar bien el **password_verify**  dice que necesito dos parametro por eso coloque dos vcs la variable contrasena

Comment: El manual en español dice que le pasas el pass que ingreso el usuario, y el hash que guardaste en la db. Eso esta aca: http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php. Entonces pasale los parametros que corresponde

Comment: @programavzla  Revisa esta respuesta, en ella encontrarás un ejemplo:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%c3%b1a-con-php-y-db/166704?r=SearchResults#166704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que volver a pasarle la contraseña con el hash que has utilizado antes.

```
$hash=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$desencriptar_contrasena = password_verify($contrasena, $hash);
```

Comment: ese "rasmuslerdorf" q colcoas a q te refieres ?

Comment: lo q pasa es q el password_hash lo tengo en el insert into del registro de usuario ... como colocaria ese **$desencriptar_contrasena = password_verify($contrasena, $hash);** que me indicas tu si el $hash esta en otra hoja diferente

Comment: o sea el insert into esta en validacion.php y el inicio de sesion esta en validar.php

Comment: Entonces recuperalo de la tabla, haz un select de la contraseña con el hash que tendrás guardada en tu tabla.

Comment: El "rasmuslerdorf" es un ejemplo de la wiki, es la contraseña que tienes.