# error con login js php

Tags: php, php7, hash

Encripte la contrasela con **password_hash** y o registra sin problema e. inconveniente es cuando intento iniciar sesion el sistema me lanza el msj de error como si la contraseña o usuario estuviese incorrecto ****Error!** Algo hizo mal... verfique e intentelo de nuevo.**

en el registro de usuario use **password_hash** para encriptar
luego en el login uso el **password_verify** y dice que algo salio mal y no inicio sesion

el error me parece queesta en **password_verify**

-------codigo de registro usuario y login---------

```
      $nombre=       $_POST   ['nombre'];
      $apellido=     $_POST   ['apellido'];
      $contrasena=   $_POST   ['contrasena'];
      $tipo_ci=  $_POST   ['tipo_ci'];
      $cedula=       $_POST   ['cedula'];
      $rol=    $_POST   ['rol'];

      $pass_fuerte = password_hash($contrasena, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$result=$bd->query("INSERT INTO usuario ( nombre ,apellido , contrasena, id_tipo_ci_id, cedula, rol_id_rol )VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$pass_fuerte','$tipo_ci', '$cedula', '$rol') ");


if($result ==true){

echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "message" => " <script type='text/javascript'>swal('Buen Trabajo', 'Ya solicito Una Clase!', 'success');</script>"));


}else{

echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "message" => " <script type='text/javascript'>swal('Discuple !', 'No se ha podido realizar el registro!', 'error');</script>", "ins"));

 }

 



    $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
    $pass_fuerte = $_POST['contrasena'];
    
    
    
    $t=$bd->query("SELECT * from usuario where cedula = '$cedula' and contrasena = '$pass_fuerte' " );

        $hash=password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$desencriptar_contrasena = password_verify($contrasena, $hash);

if (!empty($t->num_rows) && $t->num_rows == 1)
{

    $row=$t->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $_SESSION['usuario_id']=$row['usuario_id'];
    $_SESSION['cedula']=$row['cedula'];
    $_SESSION['password_verify($contrasena,$pass_fuerte)'] = $row['$pass_fuerte'];
    $_SESSION['apellido']=$row['apellido'];
    $_SESSION['nombre']=$row['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['rol']=$row['rol_id_rol'];    


    if ($row['rol_id_rol']=='1' || $row['rol_id_rol']=='2')
    {
            ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">window.location='index.php';</script>

     

   <?php

         }

   }else{

    ?>

      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">

  <strong>Error!</strong> Algo hizo mal... verfique e intentelo de nuevo.
</div>
    <?php

   }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [password\_hash y password\_verify como usarlos - problema en php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244533/password-hash-y-password-verify-como-usarlos-problema-en-php) PD: Por si no se ocurre como, primer buscas el usuario por su cedula y luego comparas la contraseña ingresada con hash guardado usando `password_verify`

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en tu variable $result -> insert into no le estas mandando la columna de password.
Debería ir de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO usuario ( nombre ,apellido , PASSWORD, id_tipo_ci_id, cedula, rol_id_rol )VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$pass_fuerte','$tipo_ci', '$cedula', '$rol') ");
```

Comment: eso correcto borre la parte de la contrasea en el insert into ya lo acomode

Comment: Si acepta campos nulos los registra normal como nulos.

Comment: @JOSEMORIANO, no seria el caso, porque estaba enviando mas datos de los que esta esperando

Comment: Una pregunta, veo que a $pass_fuerte le asignas el POST[contrasena] que recibes del html, al momento del select, este compara ese dato con lo que esta registrado, osea la contrasena encriptada, lo lógico es que eso cause el error.