# Encriptar contraseñas e inicio de sesión

Tags: php, postgresql, login, contraseña

muy buenas a todos, tengo dudas sobre como implementar el encriptado de contraseñas y su verificación a la hora de iniciar sesión en el sistema.

Aquí es donde realizo la creación de un nuevo usuario y lo guardo en mi ba

```php
<?php

require_once("conexion.php");

  $nombre_usuario =  $_REQUEST['nombre_usuario'];
  $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
  $contrasena = $_REQUEST['contrasena'];
  $correo =  $_REQUEST['correo'];
  $tipousuario =  $_REQUEST['tipousuario'];
  $estatus =  $_REQUEST['estatus'];



// if ($nombre_usuario!="" and $usuario!="" and $correo!="" and $tipousuario="" and $estatus!="" and $contrasena!="") {
    $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre_usuario, usuario, contrasena, correo, tipousuario, estatus  ) VALUES ('$nombre_usuario','$usuario', '$contrasena','$correo', '$tipousuario', '$estatus') ";
// }

  //$query;
$resultado =pg_query($con, $query);
if($resultado){
  echo 1;
}else{
  echo 2;
}
?>
```

Luego aquí es donde realizo la verificación de datos al momento de realizar el longin en el sistema.

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    include_once('conexion.php');
    $mensakeOk= false;
    $mensajeError= "El sistema no se encuentra disponible";

    if (isset($_POST['Usuario'],$_POST['Contrasena'])) {
        if ($_POST['Usuario']!="") {
            if (($_POST['Contrasena']!="")){
                $Usuario=$_POST['Usuario'];
                $Contrasena=$_POST['Contrasena'];
                $consulta=pg_query($con,("Select * from usuarios WHERE usuario='$Usuario' and contrasena='$Contrasena' and estatus='1' "));
                if (pg_num_rows($consulta)>0) {
                    $mensakeOk=true;
                    $Usua=pg_fetch_array($consulta);
                    $_SESSION['id']=$Usua[0];
                    $_SESSION['Usuario']=$Usua[1];
                    $mensajeError= "Ingreso exitoso";
                }else{
                    $mensajeError= "Contraseña incorrecta o usuario incorrecto";
                }

            }else{
                $mensajeError= "Contraseña vacia";
            }
        }else{
            $mensajeError= "Usuario vacio";
        }
    }else{
        $mensajeError= "Todos los campos son requeridos";
    }

    $salidaJson= array('respuesta'=> $mensakeOk,'mensaje' => $mensajeError);
    echo json_encode($salidaJson);
?>
```

Como debería realizar la encriptacion y luego la verificación de la misma, más o menos tengo una idea de hacerlo con password_has() pero no estoy totamente seguro.

Comment: Revisate esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%c3%b1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704 y la documentacion de [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php) y [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con la funcion [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) y [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php):

```
$pass = "password"; // o en tu caso $_REQUEST['contrasena'];
$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

echo $hash; // tu contrase;a cifrada

echo "\n";

// verificando el password
$pass = "password"; // o en tu caso $_POST['Contrasena'];
$dbhash = $hash; //  o en tu caso seria la contrase;a guardad en base de datos

if(password_verify($pass, $dbhash)){
    echo "la contrase;a es correcta";
}
```

**nota:** la columna contrase;a en la base de datos se configua a **255**

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f720352f4caacec01213f0b66d9e00f96189312)

Answer (score 0):

Pues como dices tú, puedes usar `password_hash()` y almacenarlo en una variable.
Tienes [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) más información (y ejemplos) del funcionamiento de dicha función.

Luego con `password_verify()` compruebas que la password coincide con el hash que has almacenado en la variable.