# ¿Porque me regresa el error de que no es la contraseña correcta si es la misma que la de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, login

```
if($query->num_rows>0){
    //validar contraseña
    $datos=$query->fetch_assoc();
    if(password_verify($acceso,$datos['acceso'])){
        $_SESSION['usuario']=array('Id'=>$datos['Id'],'usuario'=>$datos['usuario']);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['alert']=array('warning','Esa no es la cotraseña correcta');
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['alert']=array('warning','El nombre de usuario no existe');
}
```

Comment: Falta información. Como estás guardando la data en al DB? Es un hash? Que hay dentro de `$acceso`? Y dentro de `$datos['acceso']`?

Comment: Puedes revisar la respuesta que di en esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%C3%B1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704

Answer (score 1):

Hola **IsmaelNatividad**, la funcion **password_verify ()** resive dos parámetros un **string $password** y un **string $hash** (Este **hash** debe ser igual que el hash de la variable **$password**)

En tu código al parecer confundes con la función **strcmp()** que compara dos String.

Para obtener el hash de nuestra contraseña hacemos uso de la función **password_hash()** que resive dos parámetros, el String del que queremos obtener el **hash**, y  el algoritmo con el que se desea trabajar, por  DEFAULT es  BCRYPT, y producirá un resultado de 60 caracteres, entonces puedes usar **PASSWORD_DEFAULT**

Usando **password_verify()**  el código quedaría de esta forma.

```
if($query->num_rows>0){
    $datos=$query->fetch_assoc();
    //Obtenemos el hash de $datos['acceso']
    $datoAcceso=password_hash($datos['acceso'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    //validar contraseña
    if(password_verify($acceso,$datoAcceso)){
        $_SESSION['usuario']=array('Id'=>$datos['Id'],'usuario'=>$datos['usuario']);
    }else{
        $_SESSION['alert']=array('warning','Esa no es la cotraseña correcta');
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['alert']=array('warning','El nombre de usuario no existe');
}
```

Te invito a echarle un ojo a la documentación de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)