# validacion con password_verify

Tags: php, mysql, php7, mysqlconnector

Tengo un problema que no se como validar sesion estoy utilizando password_hash y tengo el siguiente codigo en validacion y no eh podido validar  este es el codigo

```
public function login($usuario, $password)
{
    $rows      = null;
    $statement = $this->bd->prepare("SELECT * from usuarios where username =:usuario AND password=:password");
    $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
    if ($statement->rowCount() == 1) {
        $result                 = $statement->fetch();
        $_SESSION['nombre']     = $result['nombre_usuario'] . "" . $result['apellido'];
        $_SESSION['id']         = $result['id_usuario'];
        $_SESSION['tipo_nivel'] = $result['tipo_nivel'];
        $_SESSION['estado']     = $result['estatus'];
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: En esta respuesta que di hace algún tiempo puedes ver el uso de `password_verify` y `password_hash` https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/166704/38103 la contraseña no debes añadirla a la consulta, si no una vez que has obtenido el usuario verificar que la contraseña para el usuario es valida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No debes buscar el usuario en la base de datos por la contraseña, debes hacerlo por el campo único, en tu caso entiendo que es `username`, una vez que has recuperado el usuario de la base de datos es cunado debes utilizar `password_verify` para comprobar si la contraseña es válida y en caso de serlo hacer lo que corresponda.

Te expongo un ejemplo comentado basado en tu código:

```
public function login($usuario, $password)
{
    // $rows      = null; esto no se utiliza
    // No pasamos la contraseña en la consulta y añadimos un LIMIT 1
    $statement = $this->bd->prepare("SELECT * from usuarios where username = :usuario LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    // No pasamos la contraseña en la consulta
    //$statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();

    // Comprobamos si se ha recuperado el usuario y lo asignamos
    if (!$result = $statement->fetch()) {
        // No existe el usuario y retornamos false o hacemos lo que corresponda
        return false;
    }

    // si existe el usuario verificamos la contraseña
    if (!password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
        // la contraseña no es válida, retornamos false o hacemos lo que corresponda
        return false;
    }

    // si existe el usuario y la contraseña es válida asignamos el usuario a la session
    // y retornamos true
    $_SESSION['id']         = $result['id_usuario'];
    $_SESSION['estado']     = $result['estatus'];
    $_SESSION['nombre']     = $result['nombre_usuario'] . ' ' . $result['apellido'];
    $_SESSION['tipo_nivel'] = $result['tipo_nivel'];
    return true;
}
```

Documentación y enlaces que te pueden ayudar:

- [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)
- [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)
- [Ejemplo de uso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%C3%B1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704)

Answer (score 0):

Como lo dice en la documentación de PHP , `password_verify ( string $password , string $hash ) : bool` , la función `password_verify()` necesita dos parámetros string, el `$password` que es el string puro del ususario y el `$hash` , que es el que está almacenado en la DB , entonces primero debe extraer de la DB el hash , imagino que estará en una columna llamada password , extraer ese dato y enviárselo a la función `password_verify ($password(string puro), $hash(el de la DB))` , ésto le retornará true , si coincide y false , si no coincide.

Comment: Si, lo que no se es como meterlo a la cosulta del sql

Comment: El primero es sensillo pide el parametro que ingresaron desde el formulario y el segundo no se como tomar el almacenado en la bd y acomodarlo a la consulta que temgo en el codigo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ah funcionado a la perfeccion con tu valiosa ayuda

Comment: @Camilo34 Genial, soy nuevo en stackOverFlow y me alegra haber contribuído :)