# La Query no lee la contraseña encriptada para comparar con la base de datos

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin, pdo, sha256

El problema que obtengo es cuando trato de ingresar información a un formulario de logeo, ingreso el usuario y contraseña que tengo en la base de datos **(las contraseñas están encriptadas con sha256)**.

**Imagen del problema:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El codigo es el siguiente:** **(El codigo es exprimental)**

```
<?php 

    require_once '../../config/connection.php';

        if(!empty($_POST['User'] || !empty($_POST['Password']))){

            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            
                $User = $_POST['User'];
                $Pass = $_POST['Password'];
    
                $encryptedPassword = hash('sha256',$Pass); 
    
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usario WHERE User=?';
                $stm = $con->prepare($sql);
                $stm->execute(array($User, $encryptedPassword));
                $result = $stm->fetchAll();
    
                if (count($result) > 0) {
                    foreach ($result as $data) {
                        if(password_verify($encryptedPassword, $data['Contra'])){
                            if($data['Rol'] == 'admin'){
                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION['admin'] = $User;
                                $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['Rol'];
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                                echo json_encode(array("result" => $_SESSION['rol']));
                                //header('Location: ../admin.php');
                            }else if($data['Rol'] == 'moderator'){
                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION['moderator'] = $User;
                                $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['Rol'];
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                                echo json_encode(array("result" => $_SESSION['rol']));
                                //header('Location: ../inventario.php');
                            }else if($data['Rol'] == 'user'){
                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION['moderator'] = $User;
                                $_SESSION['rol'] = $data['Rol'];
                                $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
                                echo json_encode(array("result" => $_SESSION['rol']));
                                //header('Location: ../inventario.php');
                            }
                        }else{
                            echo json_encode('Contraseña incorrecta');
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array('result' => true));
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode('No se permiten espacios vacios');
        }
?>
```

Siendo mas especifico me gustaria saber que debo hacer para que la query pueda leer la contraseña encriptada y se compare con la que existe en la base de datos.

**Base de datos por si es de utilidad:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 2 errores a primera vista, no debes utilizar `hash` para volver a cifrar la contraseña. Cuando invocas `password_verify` le estás pasando los parámetros al revés, primero recibe la contraseña en plano(lo que ha escrito el usuario) y como segundoparametro la contraseña cifrada (la que tienes en base de datos)

Comment: Está respuesta te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360919/validacion-con-password-verify/361008#361008

Comment: Muchas gracias, probare correguir lo que me mencionas. Cuando dices plano te refieres a como es capturado la contraseña desde POST?

Answer (score 1):

**Respuesta reeditada:**

Recomiendo leerse el comentario de @Xerif a esta respuesta para información adicional sobre como validar la contraseña una vez corregido el error de PDO.

---

En la consulta `$sql` hay un par de errores, a saber:

1. La tabla no se llama `usario` sino `usuario`
2. El campo no se llama `User` sino `Usuario` (aparece en la captura del phpmyadmin)

Por lo tanto tiene que quedar así:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE Usuario=?';
```

Y en la ejecución de la consulta estas pasando dos valores de inserción, cuando solo necesitas uno, el del `Usuario`, por lo tanto debe quedar así:

```
$stm->execute(array($User));
```

Con eso el error del PDO mostrado en tu captura deberia desaparecer.

Para el resto de verificaciones de contraseña revisa los comentarios de Xerif tanto en la pregunta como en esta respuesta.

Comment: Si la contraseña está correctamente cifrada por ejemplo con `password_hash` buscar por usuario y contraseña en la consulta SQL no va a funcionar ya que son cifrados de sentido único y cada vez que se genere el hash obtendrás uno diferente aún que el string base sea el mismo.

Comment: @Xerif: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta para que tengan en cuenta lo que comentas. Gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: masterguru, gracias por tu aporte no me di cuenta de esos errores tan evidentes, correguire los errores y inforamare que sucede. Saludos y Feliz navidad.

Comment: @JulioAndré: De hecho mi respuesta esta mal ahora que lo veo mejor, no se en que estaba pensando y eso que Xerif lo ha dicho bien claro... Simplemente quita el `$encryptedPassword` de aquí: `$stm->execute(array($User, $encryptedPassword));` dejandolo asi `$stm->execute(array($User));` para librarte del error de PDO, y el resto hazle caso a Xerif

Comment: Entiendo ya he correguido los puntos que me mencionabas anteriormente, hare lo que me dices y te aviso en breve que sucede. De echo se me olvido mencionar tines razon en lo de agregar el AND para pasarle la contraseña pero no se si funcionara

Comment: @JulioAndré: Bueno, ya he vuelto a editar mi respuesta para que quede todo un poco mas claro con mis correcciones comentadas antes

Comment: @masterguru @Xerif: Muy bien, les comento he cambiado el incriptado a **password_hash** cuando se añade un nuevo usuario, le he pasado la contraseña y usario en un array  tal cual como se recibe atraves de POST y a la funcion **password_verify** le paso como parametros la contraseña y la contraseña obtenida encriptada. Por el momento me ha funcionado perfectamente me devuelve una respuesta correcta. Agradesco su ayuda. Eñ codigo quedo de esta forma: ` $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario=? AND Contra=?';`  y  `  if(password_verify($Pass, $data['Contra'])){`

Comment: @JulioAndré: No intentes poner tanto código en un comentario. Create una respuesta directamente explicandolo todo y quedara mejor, y al cabo de unas 12 horas creo que la puedes marcar como aceptada.

Comment: @masterguru: Entiendo, me disculpo. Soy nuevo por aqui.

Comment: @JulioAndré: Veo que aun no has puesto una respuesta con tu solución. Te paso un enlace onde explican el porque es importante aceptar respuestar y como hacerlo, incluidas respuestas del propio OP (Original Poster): https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200

Comment: @masterguru Perdone mi falta, no estaba enterado. Solo tendria que describir como logre solventar el error no?

Comment: @JulioAndré No tengo que perdonar nada, discúlpame, simplemente te indico cómo funciona el sitio.  Mírate estas indicaciones que pongo a continuación, especialmente el apartado "Contesta la pregunta":  https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer y tu mismo verás lo que debas poner

Answer (score 1):

### Pasos aplicados para solventar el problema:

1. Metodo de encriptado **sha256** cambiado a **password_hash.**
2. Uso del metodo **password_verfy** para verificar la contraseña capturada por **POST**, con contraseña ecriptada, obtenida de la base de datos.
3. Errores de escritura corregidos `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario=?';`
4. Eliminacion de la query la variable `$encryptedPassword` resultado:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM usario WHERE Usuario=?';
$stm = $con->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($User));
$result = $stm->fetchAll();
```