# password_verify() siempre me detecta la contraseña como incorrecta

Tags: php, mysql, login

He buscado información sobre `password_verify()` y realmente es sencillo de comprender, sin embargo no encuentro por que no me valida la contraseña, siempre me retorna false aunque la contraseña no este encriptada y sea correcta y la contraseña que esta encriptada igual.

En la base de datos el campo se llama "contraseña" y el name del input es "password2".
La inserción de usuarios me lo hace bien con PASSWORD_BCRYPT sin embargo cuanto intento loguear siempre me salta a false aunque este buena la contraseña.

```php
<?php 

    session_start();
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        header('Location: /Progra%20Aplicada%20III/Login');
    }

    require 'DataBase.php';
    
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password2'])) {
        $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, contraseña FROM usuarios WHERE email=:email');
        $records->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $records->execute();

        $RPT = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $message = '';
    
        if (count($RPT) > 0) {
            echo($RPT['contraseña']);
            echo('<br>');
            echo($_POST['password2']);

            if (password_verify($_POST['password2'], $RPT['contraseña'])) {

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $RPT['id'];
                header('location: /Progra%20Aplicada%20III/Login');
            }
            else{
                $message = 'Contraseña incorrecta';
            }

        
        }
        else{
            $message = 'No existe, revise sus datos...';
        }
    }
?>
```

Hay unas preguntas similares por aquí pero no se resuelven.
He visto que dicen que necesitan ver que retornan los parámetros que doy y lo que retorna la variable que almacena la contraseña encriptada y pues lo que me devuelve esta bien por que la encriptación me la da correcta y la contraseña que retorna `$POST('contraseña')` igual.
No se que podrá ser o si he utilizado mal password_verify();

Comment: Para que password_verify la contraseña contra la que validar debe estar en hash con password_hash por ejemplo. Revisa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166666/verificar-contrase%c3%b1a-con-php-y-db/166704#166704

Comment: Hay varias cosas que pueden estar ocurriendo: 1. ¿Al hacer el INSERT de la contraseña usaste `password_hash`? Muéstranos tu código de inserción para comprobarlo. 2. El tamaño o tipo de la columna de constraseña puede ser no adecuado o no tener la extensión requerida y el hash queda truncado y por eso no coincide. Dinos de qué tipo y tamaño es tu columna. 3. Hay problemas de codificación. En todos los contextos, evita toda nominación usando `ñ`, acentos y caracteres problemáticos. Si no hilas fino en la codificación esos caracteres pueden romper el código... Revisa esas 3 cosas y nos dices.